# VMWare WinXP Internal Bluetooth on Mac

Tags: bluetooth, windows-xp, vmware

I have a MacBook Pro running Windows XP (32-bit) through VMWare Fusion. I am trying to run a LabVIEW program through WinXP that sends data from my laptop to another laptop via Bluetooth.

I can't seem to get this to work. I have checked "Share Bluetooth devices with Windows" through VMWare but I am not able to turn on discovery through WindowsXP or even search for devices through WinXP. This Code 43 error shows up and I'm not sure how to get this up and running.

Every time I try to make my WinXP Bluetooth discoverable I get the following error message:

"An error occurred while Windows was saving your settings. The following settings were not saved:

- Discoverability settings
- Connection settings"

Does anyone have a fix or idea on how to go about getting this resolved?

**Device Properties:**

Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio Ltd.

Name: Generic Bluetooth Radio

Type: Bluetooth Radios

Location: 0 (Virtual Bluetooth Adapter)

Device Status: Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. [Code 43]

Thank you,
JP

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving the issue. Apparently Bluetooth cannot be shared between both OS X and VMWare simultaneously so the "Share Bluetooth with Windows" box should be left unchecked. Also, the Apple Windows drivers for Bluetooth (used for BootCamp) need to be installed.

"AppleBluetoothBroadcomInstaller.exe"

"AppleBluetoothEnablerInstaller.exe"

"AppleBluetoothInstaller.exe"

The above drivers can be found by following [this guide](http://www.trackpadmagic.com/blog/25-bootcamp-40-drivers.html). You will need the specified version of 7zip (4.65) to access the driver directory.

If you don't initially have the option in "USB & Bluetooth Settings" to connect to the "USB Bluetooth Host Controller", restart VMWare and it should be there.

Hope this can help someone later down the line.

Again, I am running Mac OS X Lion (10.7) and VMWare Fusion 5 Windows XP Pro.

Cheers,
JP